# How to place Popup over overlay

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I try to create a modal component that is positionned over an overlay div, as in the image below.[image]

this is my html code :

```
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="overlay"></div>
      <popup></popup>      
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./vue-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the css code :

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed; 
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
  z-index: 2; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

#popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 33%;
  right: 33%;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

The problem is that the popup appear behind the overlay and not over it. Like this : [image] and I don't understand why or how I can fix it.

Comment: Give it a higher `z-index`

Comment: Try to add to `#popup` property `z-index: 3`.

Comment: Indeed, this is the thing I missed. Thank you @Matthew and @Brebber!

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index` to specify stack order.

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed; 
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
  z-index: 2; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

#popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 33%;
  right: 33%;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```